# Making a sortable ListView in Android by time for my code

Tags: android, sorting, listview, adapter

- I tried many ways but I don't to want sort it by time ...
- I want to show old item in latest
- Thanks i don't know how or what method to use and where should I copy my adapter class with full details

Here is the source code:

```
public class AdapterImage extends ArrayAdapter<StructureImage> {

    public AdapterImage(ArrayList<StructureImage> array) {
        super(G.context, R.layout.adapter_images, array);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        public ViewGroup layoutRoot;
        public TextView  txtTitle;
        public TextView  txtTozih;
        public ImageView imgPreview;


        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            layoutRoot = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutRoot);
            txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtTozih = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTozih);
            imgPreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        }


        public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<StructureImage> adapter, final StructureImage item, final int position) {
            txtTitle.setText(item.title);
            txtTozih.setText(item.tozihat);
            imgPreview.setClickable(true);
            imgPreview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(G.context, txtTitle.getText() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            String filename = item.thumbnail.replace("/thumbnail/", "");
            final File imageFile = new File(G.DIR_FINAL + "/" + filename);
            if ( !imageFile.exists()) {
                imgPreview.setImageBitmap(null);
                DownloadManager.addToDownloadList(item.thumbnail);
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //options.inSampleSize = 8;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);
            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



        }
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        StructureImage item = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_images, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.fill(this, item, position);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me take a stab at this as it seems there is enough interest. One way accomplish showing the oldest first is to sort the list in the constructor:

```
public class ListObject {
    String name;
    long timestamp;

    public ListObject(String name, long timestamp) {
        this.name = name;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}

public class SortedObjectArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListObject> {
    public SortedObjectArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ListObject> listItems) {
        super(context, resource, sortList(listItems));
    }

    static List<ListObject> sortList(List<ListObject> list) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ListObject>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ListObject left, ListObject right) {
                return (left.timestamp < right.timestamp) ? -1 : ((left.timestamp > right.timestamp) ? 1 : 0);
            }
        });
        return list;
    }
}
```